# pt-table-checksum - Diffs cannot be detected because no slaves were found (1)

Tags: mysql, replication, percona-tools

I'm new to Percona tools. I am trying to use `pt-table-checksum` as follows:

```
pt-table-checksum h=localhost -u root -p xyz--replicate=percona.checksums --create-replicate-table --databases=mysql
```

But get the error.

```
Diffs cannot be detected because no slaves were found

Please read the --recursion-method documentation for information.
```

My.cnf

```
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
datadir=/spacedb
socket=/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
max_connections = 300

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysqladmin]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysql]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
password   = user

[mysqld1]
socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock
port       = 3306
pid-file   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
datadir    = /spacedb
language   = /usr/share/mysql/english
server-id  = 1
log-bin    = mysql-bin
binlog_format = mixed

# Expire_logs + MaxBinlogSize
expire_logs_days = 7
max_binlog_size = 100M

sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1

init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
max_connections = 300

[mysqld2]
socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock2
port       = 3307
pid-file   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
datadir    = /repdb
language   = /usr/share/mysql/english
server-id  = 2
relay-log  = mysqld2-relay-bin

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Do I have to use DSN? And how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-checksum.html#cmdoption-pt-table-checksum--recursion-method) on `--recursion-method`

> Preferred recursion method for discovering replicas. Possible methods
>   are:
>
> ```
> METHOD       USES
> ===========  ==================
> processlist  SHOW PROCESSLIST
> hosts        SHOW SLAVE HOSTS
> dsn=DSN      DSNs from a table
> ```
>
> The processlist method is the default, because SHOW SLAVE HOSTS is not
>   reliable. However, the hosts method can work better if the server uses
>   a non-standard port (not 3306). The tool usually does the right thing
>   and finds all replicas, but you may give a preferred method and it
>   will be used first.
>
> The hosts method requires replicas to be configured with report_host,
>   report_port, etc.
>
> The dsn method is special: it specifies a table from which other DSN
>   strings are read. The specified DSN must specify a D and t, or a
>   database-qualified t. The DSN table should have the following
>   structure:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `dsns`
> (
>    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
>    `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `dsn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> );
> ```
>
> To make the tool monitor only the hosts 10.10.1.16 and 10.10.1.17 for
>   replication lag and checksum differences, insert the values
>   h=10.10.1.16 and h=10.10.1.17 into the table. Currently, the DSNs are
>   ordered by id, but id and parent_id are otherwise ignored.

You could do this setup for DSN if you want, but you do not have to go that far yet. Why?

The default `--recursion-method` is the processlist. This simply means that you did not run `START SLAVE;` on the port 3307 instance. You cannot use `--recursion-method` processlist on a Master where all the Slaves are stopped. When you run `START SLAVE;` on port 3307, a DB Connection should appear in the processlist of the Master (3306 instance) from the Slave (3307 instance). In light of this, you should just run `START SLAVE;` on port 3307 and then run the `pt-table-checksum`.

Give it a Try !!!